# Is there any Special way to save posts like directories with /post-name?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to php and wordpress. I know that wordpress saves all my posts in the database and retrieves it when i visit a post page, but as we all know, any post is saved in the form www.blogname.com/2013/02/11/Post-Name/

From what i know '/' in the address bar indicates a directory.

So my question is, when i write a post, and it saves in /post-name , is there an index.php file in that directory which retrieves the post from the data base? or is /post-name any way of passing information to the blogname.com to select the post saved by id or something that matches 'post-name'? 
Like the normal form response using ?=& symbols?

Comment: Those types of URLs are achieved by rewrites; there isn't an actual physical directory for those posts. Check here for info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to start learning php so you can better understand whats going on with wordpress as they have said early what you are describing is url rewriting you can read more about in here http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

and if you are new to php take a look at this http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/diving-into-php-video-series/

once you understand the foundations of php, understanding wordpress will be much easier. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

they have written a re-write rule in .htaccess file for that purpose.